# How to have an free flowing overlay structure in my android activity which is scrollable in every direction?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, material-design

I am building an android app. I am new to this, I found out an interesting activity UI development, But I don't know how to describe that property properly in android terms-(I SINCERELY APOLOGIZE FOR THAT ).I am adding a video, Please consider it.[Free Flowing  multi-directional Smooth scrollable android overlay UI](https://youtu.be/kH9CeEg_D5Y) (Please turn on the subtitles on)

How to have that kind of UI overlay suppose I want to display a large image or file with multiple clickable buttons on it[I have already tried various Image loading libraries to load big size images and to make that Multidirectional scrollable].But that's not the exact thing which I want (like you can see the above mentioned reference).

So how can I execute that?

Thank you In advance for considering your time.